# construct an object from dict using cattr/attr with defaults set to None

Tags: python, python-attrs

I would like to recreate my object from a dictionary using `cattr` but it looks that this does not work with nested field set to `None`.

Here a code example that explains the problem:

```
import attr 
import cattr

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True) 
class B(object):
    b :int = 0

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True) 
class A(object):
    a :int = 0
    b: B = None

x = A(1) 
x_dict  = attr.asdict(x)
```

Now if Iry to structure my object using:

```
cattr.structure(x_dict,A)
```

I get the following error:

```
   if 'b' in o:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

One workaround is to remove None fields from the dict before call to structure :

```
del x_dict["b"]
cattr.structure(x_dict,A)
```

Do I need to do this? or there is a simpler solution

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is using dataclass an option for you?

Comment: @balderman thank you for the suggestion but I prefer to use `attrs`.

Comment: Can I share an example of dict --> dataclass (including nested objects). Its clean and cool..

Comment: @balderman of course you can.

Comment: one of the problems with dacite is it tries to do too many things - for example, perform type validation which is generally unnecessary. It's also in general slower for de/serialization than other libraries.

Answer (score 2):

`None` is not a valid `B`. You should define `b` to be of type `Optional[B]`:

```py
from typing import Optional
import attr
import cattr


@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class B(object):
    b: int = 0


@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class A(object):
    a: int = 0
    b: Optional[B] = None


x = A(1)
x_dict = attr.asdict(x)
cattr.structure(x_dict, A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a dataclass based solution

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List
from dacite import from_dict



@dataclass
class Dog:
    name:str
    age:int

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    dogs: List[Dog] = None


data1 = [{'name':'jack','dogs':[{'name':'bark','age':12},{'name':'jumpy','age':3}]}]
persons1: List[Person] = [from_dict(Person,entry) for entry in data1]
print(persons1)

data2 = [{'name':'jack'}]
persons2: List[Person] = [from_dict(Person,entry) for entry in data2]
print(persons2)
```

output

```
[Person(name='jack', dogs=[Dog(name='bark', age=12), Dog(name='jumpy', age=3)])]
[Person(name='jack', dogs=None)]
```